# Using xline() with values from a matrix in Stata

Tags: stata

I am using `xline()` to add vertical lines to scatter plots in Stata. I stored the values for the lines, which are the means for different subsamples, in a matrix. Now I want to use the values from the matrix as coordinates in `xline()`.

I tried:

```
mat means=J(1,5,.)
mat means[1,1]=mean(subsample1)
...

scatter data1 data2, xline(means[1,1])
scatter data3 data4, xline(means[1,2])
...
```

However, I get the error `invalid line argument`.

I am grateful for any hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// open some example data
sysuse nlsw88, clear

// create a matrix of means
reg grade ibn.race, hascons
matrix means = e(b)

// use those means in -xline()-
scatter wage grade, xline(`=el(means,1,1)' `=el(means,1,2)' `=el(means,1,3)')
```